# Kendo Grid Batch destroy, how to get ID's to delete?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to process batch delete request, so i deleted some rows from grid and i clicked on save changes button.

For example:

I deleted two items from grid, but after save changes click button i get only first item ID using:

```
 console.log("delete id: " +options.data.id);
```

Delete request is processed two times but I get only one Id.

How i should to do batch delete in right way?

Thanks for any advice:

**Here is example of delete method:**

```
// DELETE FUNCTION
destroy: function (options) {
    console.log("delete");
    console.log(options.data);
    // add data to request params
    console.log("delete id: " +options.data.id);
    // call the service
    ApiService.doHttpRequest("POST", $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "/location/delete", requestParams)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // successful data retrieval
            console.log("request success, checking state");
            console.log(data);
            // sent status to global HTTP status service
            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
            console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
            // do something with data
            switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                case true:
                    options.success(data);
                    break;
                case false:
                    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                    break;
            }
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
            console.log("Processing error with status " +status);
            growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
            // hide loading spinner
            kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
        });
},
```

Comment: Did you set `batch: true` on the grid? It should be posting all of the items (not just he ids) that you deleted to the server.

Comment: You should look into using the kendo DataSource with your Grid.  It's much easier than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

options is an array. Every time you select a row to delete the data gets populated in to the options array. So the clicked row is the last index of the options array. To get the selected row id you can simply do this.

```
                  var len = options.models.length;
                  var curr = options.models[len - 1];
                  var id = curr.Id;
```